# How to fix HTML from WCF-webservice in AJAX Client Side-templates

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax, decode, client-side

I have a problem with my templates, when I return HTML, it's encoded by default, and I cannot find a way to "fix" it.

I want to replace NewLines (`\u000a`) with a straight `<br />`, but I always end up with `&amp;lt;br&amp;gt`;

I've tried to fix it with this function:

```
function cleanNewLines(text)
{
   return $("<div>" + text.replace(/\u000a/ig, "<br />") + "</div>").html();
}
```

But without any luck.

I call bind the template with: `{{cleanNewLines(NoteText)}}`

What I am trying to accomplish is the ability to render HTML with client-side templates, so if my database contains newlines, I want to be able to replace them with a `<br />`-tag

So if my database contains the string `Hi\u000aThis is a test`, I want to replace the `\u000a` with a `<br />`, so that the string would be `Hi<br />This is a test`

Comment: This needs better examples for both the encoded string and the desired result.

Comment: Added an example on how I want it to work, it's just that I want to be able to put html in my client-side templates, without it getting encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by taking the data-container into consideration:

```
function cleanNewLines(sender, args) 
{
    var data = $("#divNotes");
    data.html(data.html().replace(/\u000a/ig, "<br />"));
}
```

So when I call the dataview:onrendered I added the `cleanNewLines`-function and it replaced all newlines (even the ones it shouldn't replace), but I just removed the newlines from the original html and that solved it.

Note: I use jQuery to get the .html()-function